# Powershell (pwsh) output to file AND console

Tags: powershell

I saw many suggestions about this on SO but not getting it to work properly.
I am running build command in Powershell (pwsh) and it gives long output of building C++ projects. I want all of this output in Console and also want to save it to file.

What I tried:

1. `Tee-Object`

```
tbuild2.ps1 | Tee-Object -FilePath "E:\ToolsPath\Temp\testfile2.log"
```

It is not saving all the output. It saves some very small part of it. Not sure what that is about. Am I using it correctly?

2. This does the job of saving to file but does not show it in Console.

```
$(
   my script goes here
) *>&1 > E:\ToolsPath\Temp\Console.log
```

3. This does not save all output to file. My guess is it is saving only what is visible on Console to the file?

```
Start-Transcript -path E:\ToolsPath\Temp\ConsoleMe.log -append
tbuild2.ps1
Stop-Transcript
```

4. https://github.com/ritchielawrence/mtee/tree/master
   Not working. Is this only for cmd?

---

Update:

As suggested in comments, following solution gives output to console and to file. But the console output changed the color and now is all red as shown in the image.

```
tbuild2.ps1 *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath "E:\ToolsPath\Temp\testfile2.log"
```

[image]

Comment: in your 2nd example you're using `*>&1` and since it's working correctly this implies you're using cmdlets that output to other powershell streams than success and error. in which case, `tbuild2.ps1 *>&1 | Tee-Object...` should also work

Comment: It does give output at both places but now all output in console is red which I do not want. What changed the font color?

Comment: can't tell without seeing the content of `tbuild2.ps1` or add a screenshot to have a perspective of the issue

Comment: Added screenshot

Comment: mmm what are you using to build your c++ project ? does it have some kind of parameter / flag to "opt-out" of color in its output ?

Comment: It is custom tooling and I was looking at its documentation. It says that one of the things it does is "Log output with status to *.log and errors to *.err. It also makes the output have pretty colors." But it was not red when I did not use `Tee-Object`

Comment: try with `$PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'PlainText'` before running your build script

Comment: sorry for more complaints but now it is all white. Pretty colors are gone. e.g. warnings were yellow, success was green and errors red. But now it is all white.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md):

```bash
& { 
  $PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'Ansi'
  .\tbuild2.ps1 *>&1 | Tee-Object \\.\CON > E:\ToolsPath\Temp\Console.log
}
```